# how to use python sympy to solve for 3 unknowns with 3 equations

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

i have 3 equations:

165 ⋅ 2 ⋅ 1 = 0.310 ⋅ 2 ⋅  + 0.517 ⋅ 2 ⋅

165 ⋅ 2 = 0.173 ⋅  + 0.517 ⋅

1 + 2 = 1.0

I reorganized the first 2 equations to equal Y1 and Y2 then entered them into python:

```
import sympy as sp

n,Y1,Y2 = sp.symbols('n Y1 Y2')
Y1= ((.310*2*n)+(.517*2*n))/(165*2)
Y2= ((.173*n)+(.517*n))/(165)
print ("Y1=", Y1,"Y2=", Y2,"n=", n)
```

my first question is did I set up the code right? or should I move the Y variables to the right side of the equation and label them as equation 1 and 2?

secondly, while I tried entering the 3rd equation but got a "syntax error: can't assign to operator". how would I incorporate the 3rd equation within the code? would it act more like a "limit" (I know it's not a limit but I can't think of what its called at the moment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass all three equations simultaneously and get the three variables directly using `solve` as following: Pass the three equations where in `Eq` you write the left hand side of the equation and the right hand side of the equation (or vice versa). The second argument of `solve` is the list of variables to be solved.

```
from sympy import *

n, Y1, Y2 = symbols('n Y1 Y2')
solve([Eq(((.310*2*n)+(.517*2*n))/(165*2), Y1), Eq(((.173*n)+(.517*n))/165, Y2), 
      Eq(Y1+Y2, 1)], [n, Y1, Y2])

> {n: 108.767303889255, Y1: 0.545154911008569, Y2: 0.454845088991430} # Answer
```

Comment: thanks! sometimes its stupid stuff like this that makes me wish I wasn't taught in shorthand

Comment: how to find the variables(symbols) dynamically from the equations?